# Книги про управление памятью .NET

Tags: c#, .net, книги, memory

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, книги или статьи про .NET, CLR, управление памятью, MethodTable, EEClass, как CLR создает объекты периода выполнения, структуру экземпляра объекта и т.д. 
Рихтера не достаточно.

Comment: На этом сайте общаются по-русски.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос не задан на русском языке.

Comment: Если вопрос будет переведен на русский, то закрывать как дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584

Comment: @ВОРОН, прошу прощения, перевел.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги по C# и другая литература](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-c-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0)